# multicolumn form with form framework in TYPO3 8.7

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

is there a possibility to realise a form with two or more columns with the form framework in TYPO3 8.7?

Edit: Just for clarification - i mean the form extension (form framework) for frontend forms not bootstrap.

Thanks!

Comment: multiple columns like columns in Bootstrap? why not? you just need the according HTML markup (including CSS classes)

Comment: Well, i do know how to build columns in bootstrap or in html. But i don't know how to implement this in the form extension in TYPO3 8.7. I need two columns - e.g. 10 fields in the left colums and the last 6 fields in the right column. I can't fake it with floating fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXT:form in TYPO3 >= 8.7 already has a grid feature:

[image]

The creates the basic markup. You only need to take care of the formatting.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I found this and i can realise combinations like three fields in one row followed by 1 row with one field and so on. This feature thinks in rows: 1 row with x fields in one line followed by the next row with x fields in one line and so on. Perhaps i can live with it ... But what i really need would be colums: a form with only one row with two columns in it. Left column 8 fields in 8 lines/rows, second column 4 fields in 4 lines/rows ... On small devices the second column falls under the first column. I am not able to realize it ... :-)

Comment: No, it is possible: one Grid-row with two Grid-Rows inside (length 6) and the fields inside these Grid-Rows all with length 12 for all devices. Nasty but possible :-) Thanks again.